# Service locator - a 'secure' way to identify a service has registered or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, access-modifiers, data-access, secure-coding

I'm working on a Service locator system where services could register and get requested around the codebase.

[The whole code if you're interested](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/210080-quot-Verfices-quot-a-well-written-clean-documented-and-optimized-global-access-system!).

The problem that I'm having, I'm trying to make it so that if a service instance has already registered, registration fails, I'm doing it like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Registers a service.
/// More than one instance of a service type is allowed.
/// Registration will fail if the same instance has already registered itself.
/// </summary>
public static void Register(IService service)
{
    Type type = service.GetType();
    List<IService> list = GetServiceList(type, out list);

    if (list.IsEmpty())
        dic[type] = list;
    else if (list.Contains(service))
        throw new RegistrationException("[Vervices]: Service instance: `" + service + "` has already registered!");
    else if (list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Identifier == service.Identifier) != null)
        throw new RegistrationException("[Vervices]: There already exist a service instance of id: `" + service.Identifier);

    list.Add(service);

    if (service is MonoBehaviour)
        Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(service as MonoBehaviour);
}
```

Instead of doing a `list.Contains(service)` I thought why not let each service has a `HasRegistered` - and when I register a service, I set that to true. Now the interface will look like:

```
public interface IService
{
    void Ping(Object sender);
    string Identifier { get; }
    bool HasRegistered { get; set; }
}
```

Now I could just do `if (service.HasRegistered) throw exception;` instead of `if (list.Contains(service) throw exception;`

But the problem is, that is not secure. The property has both a public setter and getter which means any outsider could come in and do `service.HasRegistered = false;`!!!

It should be set to true, ONLY inside `Register` - How can I do that? - If I make the setter private, I can't set it anywhere, if I make a `NotifyHasBeenRegistered()` inside `IService` same problem, an outsider could call it and cause problems.

How can I do what I want, in a secure way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry to ask but... why? The service locator has long been considered an anti-pattern..

Comment: I'm still not that experienced with design patterns, I'm just experiencing things to know how they work - what you said is actually new to me. However, I'm not doing something like this http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html - if that's what you meant. I'm more making a centralized center, to register stuff...

Comment: One way would be to make the services inherit from an abstract class instead of an interface. Then you can put the `HasRegistered` property in the abstract class, and set its visibility to internal to prevent any external code from setting it mistakenly. But judging form the code you linked, you can't use this solution since your services are already inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Hey @KooKiz thanks for your input. But I don't really see how that would resolve the issue, I mean even if I were to move the variable to an abstract class, how would that let me set the variable safely only in `Register`?

FYI, this is what I'm doing now actually, I have an abstract `MonoBehaviourService` class that implements `IService`, so then my services would just inherit that abstract class. But I didn't add that update to my thread, cause I just wrote it, I didn't add it to this question, cause I didn't think it would be an info of any help...

Comment: That's one of the things that is wrong with the service locator. Every component will be coupled to the locator itself. Dependency Injection provides (at least) the same benefits as the Service Locator, without the disadvantages.

Comment: Oh and I wouldn't want to force services to inherit an abstract class. Since c# is a single inheritance language, you're forcing services to _not_ inherit from any other class, which might be fundamental to whoever is implementing the service.

Comment: @vexe The `internal` keyword means that your member is only visible by code declared in the same assembly. So define your base class and your service locator in a separate assembly, set the setter as internal, and you will be guaranteed no code outside of this assembly will set the value of the property.

Comment: The services (dependencies) are injected into the class. You don't request an inventory, you are given one. You should read about "inversion of control" first: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: Ummm, @dcastro can I request services/objects when I use dependency injection, in a manner of: `Services.Request<Inventory>();`? - The thing is, I made thing cause there are things that are used all over the place, and injecting them would make a mess...

@KooKiz, I'm sorry but I'm not sure I'm following. I haven't tried once to separate code into dif assemblies...

Comment: @KooKiz I think I got what you mean. But by 'separate assembly' do you mean like separate dll?

dcastro I will certainly look into your link, cause I'm really getting tired of all this global access stuff, maybe it is not as good as I thought anyway...

Comment: I'm sure you'll find these two concepts (IoC and DI) appealing. Either way, I'll post my opinion regarding the problem you presented.

Comment: This kind of "security" is meaningless unless you have a mixed trust domain where untrusted code is sandboxed. In principle that's possible with .net, but I doubt you're using it. For example by default it is possible to use reflection to manipulate private fields.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, if the client decides to use reflection to alter the way the library works, then it's its own fault if it breaks. The library's public API should still be written in a way that it "prevents" clients from making stupid mistakes, which is what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: @dcastro Then it's about safety (preventing accidental mistakes), not security (preventing malicious attacks).

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's a good point, the two terms often get mixed up.

Comment: @vexe Yes, a separate assembly is a separate DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd stick with the `Contains` approach, for two reasons:

- The Locator should be responsible for knowing which services have been registered - not the services (Single Responsibility Principle).
- The only way to make the service unable to set the property, is to use inheritance with `internal` properties which only the locator can set. Again, forcing the service to inherit your base class is very restrictive (since c# doesn't support multiple inheritance).

If you're worried about the `Contains` performance, you could use a data structure with better performance than `List<T>`. "Skip lists" are a kind of list with properties similar to Binary Search Trees. It allows you to search for a specific item in O(log n) time, whereas `List<T>` takes O(n) time (i.e., much slower).

NGenerics provides implementations for Skip lists and several other useful data structures: https://github.com/ngenerics/ngenerics

Here's a cheat sheet for data structures performance: http://bigocheatsheet.com/#data-structures

Comment: Awesome man! Thanks a lot for all your links! - I think I'm gonna give up on this whole global access thing, and stick to this DI/IoC thing. One question though, can I use this Skip list, anywhere instead of a normal List? Is it always better?

Comment: If you wanna take a look at how other DI frameworks work, you could start with Castle Windsor or NInject. Regarding skip lists, I know they are better for searching, but I'm not sure about other operations, like worst-case insertion/deletion, etc. I would have to dig into .Net's implementation of `List<T>` to find out more. Perhaps you could post that as another question on SO? Or run a few benchmarks yourself?

Comment: About this DI thing, why are there dif frameworks? I mean, I know that DI is just injecting the variables/dependencies of a class, to its constructor... do you need a framework to do that?

Comment: @vexe `Is it always better?` If it were, `List<T>` wouldn't exist ;) Each data structure has its pros and cons, it's up to you to decide which one you should use depending on the situation

Comment: It is not as simple as you might think... For a simple project with a hand full of classes, yeah, you might wanna inject them yourself. But for a growing project, Windsor will take A LOT of work out of your hands. I'd say the best way to realize this is to try out the framework for yourself.